# Rails - dynamically add multiple nested form fields

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, nested-forms

Is there a way to dynamically add X number of nested form fields? For example if we have a select menu:

Select Menu
-1
-2
-3
-4

And the user selects 3, then create 3 nested form fields.

I have watched the Railscast on Nested model form but to me this already has the one set of fields_for already created and simply inserts them each time the link is clicked. I would like to dynamically insert X amount each time the select menu changes.

Here is some code from the Railscast:

```
def link_to_add_fields(name, f, association)
  new_object = f.object.send(association).klass.new
  id = new_object.object_id
  fields = f.fields_for(association, new_object, child_index: id) do |builder|
    render(association.to_s.singularize + "_fields", f: builder)
  end
  link_to(name, '#', class: "add_fields", data: {id: id, fields:  fields.gsub("\n", "")})
end
```

Comment: do you have answer for this?

Comment: @do_Ob no, I didn't figure it out and moved on. Have you tried `cocoon` suggested in the answer below? Apparently [version 1.2.2](https://github.com/nathanvda/cocoon/blob/d64a1e3cd2cae7bf4a8f0960a88e4ca5e8697cc4/History.md#version-122) added the ability to add multiple items in one click

Answer (score 2):

sorry for the late answer, but I was just looking around for the same thing. Had you checked this gem?
https://github.com/nathanvda/cocoon